# PHP preg_replace convert to Javascript replace

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, preg-replace

in php code im using this `preg_replace('/[^a-z%0-9.\/_]/i', '', $filename);`, May i know how to convert php preg_replace to javascript replace?

I'm convert the code into this `filename.replace(/[^a-z%0-9.\/_]/i, '');` in javascript, but the result is different.

$filename = (123).jpg

php result = 123.jpg

javascript result = 123).jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `/g` modifier to remove all occurrences:

```js
filename = "(123).jpg";
console.log(filename);
filename = filename.replace(/[^a-z%0-9.\/_]/ig, '');
console.log(filename);
```

Comment: @mic_test Sure, happy to help, the nuances of syntax can bog us down from time to time.